# How to keep text in svg when save it in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, export, svg

I am trying to save ai file as SVG that has a lot of text items but illustrator converts the text to paths, I want to keep it as a text as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what's the version of your illustrator?

I am using CC 2015, and by the default when I save the file as svg and it has text in it, it's stay as text.

When I save the file as svg, there's fonts setting, and in "Type" field, select SVG if you want the text to stay as the text.

Here's the screen:

[image: When you try to save it as SVG file]

Comment: I have the cs6 version and the default settings not keep the text as is.

Comment: The steps are the same in CS6. Regardless if it defaults to Outline Text. Just choose SVG from the Type: drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

If the artwork contains any SVG effects, select each item to which an SVG effect has been applied, and move the effect to the bottom of the Appearance panel (just above the Opacity entry). If other effects follow an SVG effect, the SVG output will consist of a raster object. In addition, if the artwork contains multiple artboards, select the artboard you want to export.

Choose File > Save As or File > Save A Copy.

Choose SVG (*.SVG) or SVG Compressed (*.SVGZ) as the file format, and click Save.

In the SVG Options dialog box, set the desired options and click OK:

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. Can you edit your answer and explain how does all of that relate specifically with the text not being converted into a path?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When exporting change the 'Font' option from 'SVG' to "Convert to outlines"

Problem would be solved

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Your second screenshot seemed to be accidentally the same as the first one. I made an edit suggestion to avoid confusion to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Outlining the text (Mac: Shift+Cmd+O) (PC: Shift+Ctl+O) for eps and svg files can often makes more sense. Usually more light-weight file (depending on font family and text amount), so might be better for web use. And printers and manufacturer usually much prefer fonts outlined. But not selectable / copyable anymore this way.